# Convert Cell to Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a cell A composed of:

'hello'
'world'
'test'

I would like to convert this to a matrix.

I tried

```
cell2mat(A)
```

Which returns

```
     Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 84)
        m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});
```

I then tried

```
 cell2mat(A')
```

Which however merges all words in a single cell.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

```
A={'hello' 'world' 'test'};
strvcat(A{:})
```